# MS-Access - You tried to execute that does not include the specified expression 'Quantity' as part of an aggregate function

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I tried to form a new query table that contain **products**, **product quantity**, **Total Product Price**, **Price per Product**, Am getting this error **"You tried to execute that does not include the specified expression 'Quantity' as part of an aggregate function".**

My Product Table Contains

```
UniqueNo ProductId   productName   Each  Qty TotalAmount
1        P101        Pen-Turbo     40    2   80
2        P102        NoteBook      150   1   150
3        P103        Scale         10    3   30
4        p102        NoteBook      150   1   150
5        p101        Pen-Turbo     40    1   40
```

Now i need to get that product sold out details that is

```
ProductId  Productname  Qty  Total Each
P101       Pen-Turbo    3    120   40
P102       NoteBook     2    300   150
P103       Scale        3    30    10
```

I tried this query but getting error 
**SELECT ProductId, Product, Qty(SUM) FROM NewInvoice_2 GROUP BY ProductId, Product**

Help me to obtain like that.
Thanks in advance

Srihari

Comment: Surely you mean `Sum(Qty)` Also, where does MySql come into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  ProductId, Product, 
  SUM( Qty ) Qty, 
  SUM( TotalAmount ) total  
FROM NewInvoice_2 
GROUP BY ProductId, Product
```